# SQL Server did not return a response

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot

I get error:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed."

hibernate config:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "sqlUserEntityManagerFactory")
public class MR2HibernateDataConfig {

    @Value("${sql.server.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Bean(name = "sqlUserDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mr.datasource")
    public DataSource sqlUserDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlUserEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sqlUserEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("sqlUserDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("ru.connection.db.model.mr")
                .persistenceUnit("mr")
                .properties(properties)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlUserTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager sqlUserTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("sqlUserEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
mr.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
mr.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;databaseName=test;
mr.datasource.username=username
mr.datasource.password=userpassword
sql.server.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
```

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

SQLServerException:

```
2018-07-18 17:57:01.663  INFO 17032 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1531911166 bytes = { 139, 176, 241, 152, 59, 164, 209, 206, 207, 140, 19, 206, 191, 85, 171, 95, 29, 128, 12, 155, 156, 132, 70, 53, 117, 195, 59, 179 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=server]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 142
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket(true)
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 5
main, received EOFException: ignored
main, called closeInternal(false)
main, close invoked again; state = 5
main, handling exception: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
main, called closeSocket()
2018-07-18 17:57:02.237 ERROR 17032 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1368) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1412) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1058) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) [spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366) [spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f609caad.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$6(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f609caad$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e421a258.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f609caad.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) [spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) [spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at ru.connection.db.DbApplication.main(DbApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:513) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:570) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:562) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:757) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:745) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1379) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    ... 77 common frames omitted

2018-07-18 17:57:02.252  WARN 17032 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
```

openssl s_client -connect server:1433

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140030916663200:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1531898121
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

what do you think?

Comment: maybe you're missing some arguments for an SSL communication in your connection string, like  `"encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";`  : [Microsoft related article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

I changed my java version from jdk-8.172 to jdk-8.152 and it worked for me.